# Angular 6 [selected] not binding with formControlName

Tags: html, angular

Using reactive forms, I have the following problem:

When the selected condition is true, the function intersect is triggered but the formControlName's value is set to 'null'.

```
      <select class="gr-select-no" formControlName="majoEnfScenario2" (change)="intersectLevels(ScenarioEnum.SCENARIO_2)">
          <option [ngValue]="null">-</option>
          <option *ngFor="let contribution of
        getContributionDeBasesWarrantyByCode(DcPtiaWarrantiesCodeEnum.MAJO_ENF)
        | filter :'membershipFeeCode':asGarScenario2
        | filterCdbByLevel:  formGroup.get('dcPtiaFormGroup').get('dcPtiaScenario2').value
        | filterCdbByLevel: formGroup.get('majoCplFormGroup').get('majoCplScenario2').value; let length = count"
                  [ngValue]="contribution" [selected]="length === 1">{{contribution?.value}}</option>
     </select>
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I don't understand. Your code says that the `intersectLevels` function should be triggered **when the user selects a new value in the dropdown** and that the `selected` binding will be true **if the collection only contains one item**. What's the connection between these two, unrelated things? Why would your `intersectLevels` function get triggered when there's only one item in the list?

Comment: Intersect is used in 3 formcontrols its useful to calculate a value based on these controls. So i want it to be executed even tho its one element in the list. Which mean inside intersect when accessing the value automatically chosen by selected tag its value is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you're manipulating the `selected` property manually instead of letting Angular's Form API do its job.

In Angular, you don't have to manually alter the `selected` property for an `<option>` to appear selected.

You can just set the value of the FormControl and the corresponding option will automatically appear as selected. Something like:

```ts
const coll = this.getContributionDeBasesWarrantyByCode(DcPtiaWarrantiesCodeEnum.MAJO_ENF);
if (coll.length === 1) {
  this.form.get('majoEnfScenario2').setValue(coll[0]);
}
```